# Module to view theme folder through drupal 7 interface

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I am working on this site http://talikulam.com/. I need to change the slideshow images. Theme setting allowing to change caption and description only. To change the images I need to go the images folder manually.

Is there any way to do this via Drupal7 interface?

A pre build module so even client can change the images easily. The slideshow is a Flex Image Slideshow.

Comment: This website is using Nexus theme , and this theme has implemented slideshow , somehow hard-coded . are you really interested in this theme? you can use flex slider and views to create slideshows by your own

Comment: Yep im going to try that as well... thanks Alireza...don't we have module to interact with file structure via durpal interface...that a question I got indirectly with this matter..?